# Loop through for loop %x% times in batch

Tags: batch-file

Okay, so let's say I have a variable, and let's call it x. And I have this loop:

```
for %%i in (%x%) do (
  REM --Code goes here--
)
```

Now, that loop would execute once, assuming x equaled something like 10. And if I wanted it to loop 10 times I could do this:

```
for %%i in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) do (
  REM --Code goes here--
)
```

But say x equaled 105, how would I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [`for /?`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) documentation for the `/L` option.

```
for /L %%A in (1,1,%x%) do (
    REM --Code goes here--
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to `for` statements, I recommend learning them

This aside here is a way I have made to loop x times without a `for` statement.

```
echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p "x= times to loop:"
goto loop

:loop
echo %x%
set /a "x=!x!-1"
if "%x%" LEQ "0" (goto getout)
goto loop

:getout
cls
echo you escaped!
pause
```

Comment: Nice technique.  Any need for the parens around `goto getout`?