# How do I loop a batch script only a certain amount of times?

Tags: loops, batch-file, echo

How do I loop a batch script only a certain amount of times (x10 or something)?
If the code was:

```
@echo off                                                                     
:loop1                                                                              
Start taskmgr.exe                                                       
Goto loop                                                                         
:loop2                                                                             
Start cmd.exe                                                                 
goto loop2
```

How can loop loop1 and few times and go to loop2?

Any helpful answer would be appreciated :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop through for loop %x% times in batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213375/loop-through-for-loop-x-times-in-batch)

Answer (score 10):

For a reason that i'm ignoring, the `FOR` command won't work for looping a specific label.
For example (I may be wrong):

```
@echo off
for /L %%a in (1,1,2) do (
goto loop
)

:loop
echo this won't loop for 2 times.
```

This will simply loop infinite times. So, I have found an alternative simple method to loop a label as many times as I want. To do this, I create a variable, like `loop` that will have an even bigger number every time the label repeats.

There is an example:

```
@echo off
set loop=0
:loop
echo hello world
set /a loop=%loop%+1 
if "%loop%"=="2" goto next
goto loop

:next
echo This text will appear after repeating "hello world" for 2 times.
```

Output:

```
hello world
hello world
This text will appear after repeating "hello world" for 2 times.
```

Explanation:

- `set loop=0` sets the value of the variable `loop` at 0;
- `set /a loop=%loop%+1` adds 1 every time the label `:loop` is repeated.
- `if "%loop%"=="2" goto next` tests if the variable `loop` is equal to `2` (so it was repeated for 2 times); if it's equal, it will go to the label `:next`, otherwise it will go to the label `:loop`.

Comment: in your first code snipped replace `goto loop` with `call :loop` (note: the `:` is optional for `goto`, but `call` needs it) and it will work.

Answer (score 8):

if you open a command window and type FOR /? it will give you the command you are looking for.

```
FOR /L %variable IN (start,step,end) DO command [command-parameters]

The set is a sequence of numbers from start to end, by step amount.
So (1,1,5) would generate the sequence 1 2 3 4 5 and (5,-1,1) would
generate the sequence (5 4 3 2 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example:

```
@echo off                                                                     
for /L %%a in (1,1,10) do (
Start taskmgr.exe          
)                                             

for /L %%a in (1,1,10) do (                                                        
Start cmd.exe                                                                 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
set /a a=1
goto loop
:loop
echo looped %a% times so far
set /a a=%a%+1
if %a%=10 (
echo looped a total of %a% times
)
```

You can also use this command:

```
@echo off
for /l %%a in (1,1,10) do (
rem %%a is a variable and starts at a value of 1, steps by 1 and ends at a value of 10
start "Command Prompt #%%a Opened" cmd
rem eg Command Prompt #1 Opened
rem eg Command Prompt #2 Opened
rem etc
)
```

which opens Command Prompt with the title "Command Prompt #%%a Opened". [`rem`](https://jpsoft.com/help/rem.htm) is a command that you can use to write [comments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment_(computer_programming)).

Comment: both methods were suggested years ago. How does your answer add additional value?

Comment: I'm just using an example from some of my batch files.

Comment: @Stephan there haven't been such example with `for` and loop variable reference

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set loopvar=1
:repeat
if %loopvar% gtr 5 (goto :done) else (set /a loopvar=%loopvar%+1 && echo Loop && goto :repeat)
:done
```

Under :done, write the code you want it to do after the loop. Make sure to replace five with the number of times you want the loop to repeat.
For delay in the loop, try this:

```
@echo off
set loopvar=1
:repeatwithdelay
if %loopvar% gtr 5 (goto :done) else (set /a loopvar=%loopvar%+1 && timeout /T 1 >nul && echo Loop && goto :repeatwithdelay)
```

Hope it helped!