# Create multiple files with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4141042/9674201) I can create multiple files a.txt, b.txt, ... , z.txt. in Bash with:

```
touch {a..z}.txt
```

Or 152 with:

```
touch {{a..z},{A..Z},{0..99}}.txt
```

How can I do this in Powershell?
I know `New-Item a.txt`, but If I want multiple files as above?

For curiosity, what are the equivalent commands in Command Prompt (cmd.exe)?

Comment: ATM there are only numeric ranges with the range operator `..` IIRC that is a feature to come with future PS versions. In windows the command wouldn't work because it doesn't distinguish between the casings. https://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/using-range-operator-to-generate-letters/

Answer (score 13):

For Powershell:

```
1..5 | foreach { new-item -path c:\temp\$_.txt }
```

The `foreach` loop will run for each number in 1 to 5, and generate a file in the desired path with the name of that number passed to the command (represented by the `$_`)

You could also write it as:

```
%{1..5} | new-item c:\temp\$_.txt
```

For cmd:

```
for /L %v in (1,1,5) do type nul > %v.txt
```

More information here: [cmd/batch looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137876/how-do-i-loop-a-batch-script-only-a-certain-amount-of-times/41810676)

Comment: The Powershell command without foreach doesn't work, but with foreach, it worked like a charm. Thanks! @sysg0blin

Answer (score 3):

Not quite as concise as bash, but it can be done.

```
@(97..(97+25)) + @(48..(48+9)) |
    ForEach-Object { New-Item -Path "$([char]$_).txt" -WhatIf }
```

Another way...

```
@([int][char]'a'..[int][char]'z') + @([int][char]'0'..[int][char]'9') |
    ForEach-Object { New-Item -Path "$([char]$_).txt" -WhatIf }
```

And one more...

```
function rng { @($([int][char]$args[0])..$([int][char]$args[1])) }

(rng 'a' 'z') + (rng '0' '9') |
    ForEach-Object { New-Item -Path "$([char]$_).txt" -WhatIf }
```

If you are desperate to do this in a cmd.exe shell, this might work. When it looks like the correct commands are produced, delete or comment out the `echo` line and remove the `rem` from the next line.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "CLIST=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,35) DO (
    CALL SET "S=%%CLIST:~%%i,1%%.txt"
    echo TYPE NUL ^>"!S!"
    rem TYPE NUL >"!S!"
)
```

Comment: Nice one (+1), but only 0..9 and the `-WhatIf` is a bit like cheating ;-)

Comment: Thank you @LotPings. The `-WhatIf` is only there to see what would happen. If you actually wanted the files created, remove `-WhatIf`.

Comment: Yes, but as windows won't allow the same file name with different casing...

Comment: Yes, you are right, @LotPings. I will remove the upper case letters.

Answer (score 3):

@Emilson Inoa Your solution is very ingenuous; there's a typo in the names, am sure you meant to exclude the extensions in the array. You'll end up with

```
("Text1", "Text2", "Text3") | % {ni -Path "/path/to/dir" -Name "$_.txt"}
```

Answer (score 2):

For letters, in PowerShell, use:

```
97..( 97+25 ) | foreach { new-item $env:temp\$( [char]$_ ).txt }
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simple, take a look:

```
("Text1.txt","Text2.txt", "Text3.txt") | foreach { New-Item -Path "X" -Name "$_.txt" }
```

You will replace X of course with the path where you want the files to be created.

If further explanation is required, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

In the PowerShell, you can use `New-Item`

```
New-Item a.txt, b.txt, c.txt
```

then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The following command in powershell will create multiple files (20) named Doc_.txt in the directory that the command is executed.

```
new-item $(1..20 | %{"Doc$_.txt"})
```

I think this command is the closest to the bash equivalent:

```
touch Doc{1..20}.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

To create Multiple Files using loops:

```
$count = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Count"
$count 
for ($i=1 ; $i -le $count;($i++)){    
New-Item -Path "<Path>\<Filename>$i.txt"
}
```

To have a static number remove the count variable to a fixed number

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question (as this method requires each file extension be provided), but a more rudimentary way is of course:

```
New-Item {a..z}.txt, {A..Z}.txt, {0..9}.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few failed attempts, I mashed a couple of the answers above to create files titled [char][int].txt: `1..5 | foreach {New-Item -Path 'X' -Name "abc$_.txt"}`, where X is the path.  Also, just to thank the original writer of the question, as it described really succinctly exactly the problem I was trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

1..1000000 | foreach {new-item -path C:\Testdata$_.txt}

This worked fine for me. Created 1M files in the C:\Testdata folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is how simple it is to create multiple files in Windows PowerShell

```
ni file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, "file 4 with spaces.txt", file5.txt
```

`ni` just stands for new item.

Now to answer your question of create multiple files a.txt, b.txt, ... , z.txt. in Bash with touch {a..z}.txt, you have 2 options:

In Powershell:

```
bash
touch {a..z}
touch {{a..z},{A..Z},{0..99}}.txt
exit
```

Or (For touch {a..z}):

```
1..26 | ForEach-Object { New-Item -ItemType File -Path ("{0}.txt" -f ([char]($_ + 96))) }
```

Or (For touch {{a..z},{A..Z},{0..99}}.txt):

```
1..26 | ForEach-Object { New-Item -ItemType File -Path ("{0}.txt" -f [char]($_ + 96)) -Force }; 65..90 | ForEach-Object { New-Item -ItemType File -Path ("{0}.txt" -f [char]::ConvertFromUtf32($_)) -Force }; 0..99 | ForEach-Object { New-Item -ItemType File -Path ("{0:D2}.txt" -f $_) -Force }
```

You have both the options of entering bash and use your regular touch command or using ForEach-Object in PowerShell. Now one important thing to remember is that unlike Linux **Windows does not distinguish between a.txt and A.txt**, so you'll end up having either a.txt or A.txt